# Squid proxy not working, using Ubuntu Server 10.04 and two NICs. One is connected to WAN and other to LAN

Tags: proxy, ubuntu-10.04, squid

I am trying to setup a proxy server but I am unable to do it. Here is the details of my setup

I have one Server(IBM X3800 series) and one Desktop PC. Server is having to network card connected to it. eth0 and eth1. eth0 is connected to WAN via global IP of 202 series and internet is working fine on server, I can connect to internet. eth1 is connected to switch and below is config in eth1

```
IP: 192.168.2.2
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.2.1
Network: 192.1968.2.0
Broadcast: 192.168.2.255
```

I have simply installed the squid proxy using `apt-get install squid`. I have changed the file

```
/etc/squid/squid.conf
```

and added the below details

```
httpd_accel_host virtual
httpd_accel_port 80
httpd_accel_with_proxy on
httpd_accel_uses_host_header on
acl lan src 192.168.2.0/24
http_access allow lan
```

and finally added these iptable rules

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to globalip:3128
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
```

where globalip is the IP of eth0.

Now the desktop PC is connected to server via switch and the ip configuration for Desktop pc is this

```
IP: 192.168.2.4
Netmaskapt-get install squid: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.2.1
Network: 192.1968.2.0
Broadcast: 192.168.2.255
```

I can easily ping from desktop to server and from server to desktop. But my desktop system cannot access the internet. So I guess that the problem is with the squid. Please help me to solve this issue. If you need any other information then please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are setting up a transparent proxy but your config does not look valid for this task. `httpd_accel_*` directives are for reverse proxying (AKA http acceleration) I believe. You should comment them out. Use `http_port 3128 transparent` instead.

Comment: I did that, but its still not working ? if you want any other information from my side, please let me know.

Comment: Does squid show any error page in a browser? What is an error, can users see anything at all in their browsers?

Comment: I cant even connect to internet. I cant ping google.com or yahoo.com via terminal.

Comment: It looks like routing is not set up on a server properly, this is not directly related to squid configuration. But you should be able to use squid even without routing enabled. I suggest you to try to configure squid in non-transparent, explicit mode first. You should change `http_port 3128 transparent` to `http_port 3128` and set up http://192.168.2.2:3128 as a proxy in browser settings.

Comment: Oh I just realized that your transparent proxy was not on your gateway. Your gateway seems to be 192.168.2.1 and your proxy is 192.168.2.2. Your desktop PC clients can't work if the transparent proxy is not on your gateway. By the way, can you access the internet from a server with the squid proxy?

Comment: Actually I am at home right now and dont have access to server (not even SSH), so I can try these changes right now, but I will tomorrow and will let you know how it went. I really appreciate you help :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a proxy sitting on a computer, but no configuration of any kind to cause other computers to use that proxy. The `iptables` settings are trying to modify packets that will never wind up on that computer because no configuration anywhere else on your network steers these packets to that computer.

The proxy only proxies HTTP, yet you are still expecting things like `ping` to work.

It sounds like what you want is NAT, not proxying. And the NAT should be set up on the machine that's the default gateway for the LAN machines.

Comment: My issue has been resolved, thanks for answering though.